# Como faço para importar um jupyter notebook ? ou abrir?

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo importar ou abrir o arquivo de um `notebook.ipynb`

Eu tentei ir até o diretório do arquivo no prompt e digitar : `jupyter notebook` nome_do_arquivo E me alega que o arquivo não é encontrado.

Comment: Eu tentei ir até o diretório do arquivo no prompt e digitar : jupyter notebook nome_do_arquivo 
E me alega que o arquivo não é encontrado.

Comment: O que é "curos de fundamentos"?

Answer (score 2):

No diretório onde está o arquivo que vc quer abrir, na linha de comando,   digite: `jupyter notebook`, e então vc tem um novo serviço "escutando" na porta 8888, veja:

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 10:51:49.289 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/sidon
[I 10:51:49.290 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 10:51:49.290 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=b7808c09d59aee2e93462fb522a71faab25eff1294882789
[I 10:51:49.290 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:51:49.290 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=b7808c09d59aee2e93462fb522a71faab25eff1294882789
[I 10:51:49.920 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 10:51:50.563 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/7977e2c8-73bf-4713-81ce-125211de1f82/channels?session_id=DA68001D28A447BF9F79B9315E67F6FA (::1): Kernel does not exist: 7977e2c8-73bf-4713-81ce-125211de1f82
[W 10:51:50.598 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/7977e2c8-73bf-4713-81ce-125211de1f82/channels?session_id=DA68001D28A447BF9F79B9315E67F6FA (::1) 60.22ms referer=None
[W 10:51:58.606 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 7977e2c8-73bf-4713-81ce-125211de1f82:DA68001D28A447BF9F79B9315E67F6FA
```

Como diz a saída do comando, agora basta vc ir em um browser e acessar o endereço: `http://localhost:8888/?token=b7808c09d59aee2e93462fb522a71faab25eff1294882789` (O token é só para a primeira vez), então vc verá todos os arquivos do diretorio, no browser, agora é só dar um duplo clique no arquivo que vc deseja abrir.

Para instalar o jupyter, veja [esse link.](http://jupyter.org/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava tentando importar pela linha de comando e não está dando certo!
mas, já desisti disso, e importei do modo tradicional ao apertar o botão de adicionar um arquivo .